# Open Application Page in Safari

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-page

Is is possible to open an Application's page from iOS in Safari?

When I try to open the following page, I'm redirected to a mobile version of Facebook on the page "**Pages You May Like**"

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:
    [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.facebook.com/pages/Appinion/130580070430657"]];
```

I'd be happy with redirecting to the full version of the site; I've tried appending `?m2w` with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically I found the answer almost straight away by experimenting a bit

The URL format for mobile versions of the page is:

```
https://m.facebook.com/pages/<APP_NAME>/<APP_ID>?id=<APP_ID>#!/profile.php?id=<APP_ID>
```

I imagine this could be shortened..